# Check ActivePresentation File type

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How can I check ActivePresentation File type and show it with msgbox?

I know how to do this in Word and Excel-

Word: msgbox activedocument.SaveFormat

Excel: msgbox ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat

Thanks

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961557/how-do-i-set-the-default-save-format-in-powerpoint

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any equivalent FileFormat/SaveFormat property in PowerPoint, so you'll probably need to look at the file's extension.

Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    MsgBox FileType(ActivePresentation.Name)

End Sub

Function FileType(sName As String) As String

    Dim sMsg As String
    Dim sExt As String

    If InStr(sName, ".") = 0 Then
        sMsg = "File hasn't been saved, so type is unknown."
    Else
        sExt = Mid$(sName, InStrRev(sName, ".") + 1)
        Select Case UCase(sExt)
            Case Is = "PPT"
                sMsg = "Powerpoint 2003 or earlier"
            Case Is = "PPTX"
                sMsg = "Powerpoint 2007 or later"
            Case Is = "PPTM"
                sMsg = "Powerpoint 2007 or later, with macros"
            Case Is = "PPS"
                sMsg = "Powerpoint 2003 or earlier SHOW file"
            Case Is = "PPSX"
                sMsg = "Powerpoint 2007 or later SHOW file"
            Case Is = "PPSM"
                sMsg = "Powerpoint 2007 or later SHOW file with macros"

            ' Add more case statements as needed

            Case Else
                sMsg = "Unknown file type (" & sExt & ")"
        End Select
    End If

    FileType = sMsg

End Function
```